# How can I vote on a proposed tag synonym?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

On the [tag synonyms page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms), I can see potential synonyms listed, and I see "pending(0)" in the right column, but I don't know how to vote on a proposed synonym.  Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 2):

On the [synonyms page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms), click on a tag in the left-hand (**Master**) column for a row labeled as *pending*.  That will take you to the synonyms page for that particular synonym.  Near the bottom of the page, there will be a section saying **Suggested synonyms** with arrows next to it that can be used to vote.

This interaction's rather unintuitive....it really ought to be possible to vote from the synonyms page itself.

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing :-)